# Can I force the scrollbar position?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar

Can I force the scrollbar of an HTML page to return in a position where it does not touch neither the top margin nor the bottom one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jump link and some script to move the user to the middle of the page which would have the scrollbar not be at the top nor the bottom.

your jump link looks like this

```
<a href="#div_id">jump link examplet</a>
```

Then make

```
<div id="div_id"></div>
```

clicking on that anchor takes you to the jump link for that div, you can script going there by document location or jquery etc..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your page. If it is not larger than the viewport, then it's not possible. If it's larger, then you can achieve your goal with this code:

```
function goto(y) {
    var x = window.scrollX;
    window.scrollTo({
        top: y,
        left: x,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}

function resolveWindow() {
    if (window.scrollY < 100) goto(100);
    else if (window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 100) goto(document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 100);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    resolveWindow();
});

resolveWindow();
```

## goto

just moves vertically to a position received as parameter, leaving the horizontal position unchanged.

## resolveWindow

Checks whether the scroll position is higher than the first 100 pixels vertically and if so, it moves downward.

Checks whether you are below the bottom 100 pixels.

**Alarm**: If your page is smaller than the viewport, this can run into an infinite loop, so you might want to wrap a conditional around this, like

```
if (100 < document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 100) {
    //Your code
}
```

Note: instead of 100 you can use any limits that you want.

## event listener

This prevents the situation you want to prevent.

## resolveWindow call

ensures that this behavior already starts and we do not need to wait for the first scroll event.